# Does Bootstrap 2.3.2 have a collapsible nav bar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a web application, which I am adding a control to.  I want to have a dynamic, horizontal series of buttons, which will collapse gradually into a dropdown menu as the space demands.  When I say dynamic, the buttons represent a number of commands which will be available to the user based on a number of application and user configurations, so it cannot be baked into the UI.  I.e., the buttons will be generated at run-time.

So, on a wide device, you may have buttons:

```
[B1] [B2] [B3] ... ... ... [Bn]
```

On a smaller width device, you may see

```
[B1] [B2] [B3] ... [Bn-x]  [DD]
```

... where [DD] contains [Bn-x+1] through [Bn]

The application already has Bootstrap 2.3.2 included, and I see the Nav / Pills stuff, but I don't see anything which dynamically piles pills into the menu.  Is there such a feature, or perhaps an extension to Bootstrap?  (Unfortunately, it's a little too late in the release cycle to upgrade to 3.x.)  Or perhaps there's a jQuery UI plugin that would suit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further Google'ing, I found [an answer](https://brianseagraves.com/blog/twitter_bootstrap_nav_tabs_overflow_dropdown) which I can modify to suit my purposes.  Imperfect, but it will work.  It looks like this functionality is not built into Bootstrap, but adding it is not a horrible task.